# how to install Redmine_RE plugin on Redmine.3.1.0

Tags: plugins, redmine

I have installed Redmine 3.1.0 on windows.I want to install Redmine_RE plugin on this version of Redmine.But when i copy the Redmine_re zip into plugins folder in the redmine and restart redmine server it is exiting with following error

```
C:\Sites\redmine-3.1.0>bundle exec rails server webrick -e production
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in production on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/acti
ve_record/scoping/named.rb:143:in `scope': The scope body needs to be callable.
(ArgumentError)
        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/plugins/redmine_re/app/models/re_artifact_pr
operties.rb:6:in `<class:ReArtifactProperties>'
        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/plugins/redmine_re/app/models/re_artifact_pr
operties.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/plugins/redmine_re/init.rb:6:in `<top (requi
red)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:155:in `block in load'

        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:146:in `each'
        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/lib/redmine/plugin.rb:146:in `load'
        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/config/initializers/30-redmine.rb:21:in `<to
p (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/engine.rb:652:in `block in load_config_initializer'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/engine.rb:651:in `load_config_initializer'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/engine.rb:616:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/engine.rb:615:in `block in <class:Engine>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block i
n tsort_each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (
2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:210:in `block (
2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:209:in `block i
n each_strongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:203:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component_from'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block i
n each_strongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_st
rongly_connected_component'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_e
ach'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/config/environment.rb:14:in `<top (required)
>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-
4.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/config.ru:in `new'
        from C:/Sites/redmine-3.1.0/config.ru:in `<main>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib
/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.3
/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

pls suggest how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove the installed plugin, switch to the branch `towards_redmine_3_compatibility` on the github page of the plugin, then download it as zip.

Do not forget to rename the extracted folder to `redmine_re`

(Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question)

Comment: Hi, thanks a log your help.The Remine server is up and running.But while trying to save requirement using Redmine_re  i am getting the following error in the  production log of redmine.      ( 'NameError (undefined local variable or method `connection' for #<ReArtifactRelationship:0x8045268>):
  lib/plugins/acts_as_list/lib/active_record/acts/list.rb:220:in `bottom_item'
  lib/plugins/acts_as_list/lib/active_record/acts/list.rb:214:in `bottom_position_in_list'
  lib/plugins/acts_as_list/lib/active_record/acts/list.rb:205:in 
Can you help me out on this @ste26054